# npm error "Keccak bindings compilation fail." while installing truffle

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, truffle, keccak

I tried to install Truffle, but then I got this error:

```
$ npm install -g truffle
    C:\Users\dany.vandermeij\AppData\Roaming\npm\truffle -> C:\Users\dany.vandermeij\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js

> keccak@1.4.0 install C:\Users\dany.vandermeij\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\keccak
> npm run rebuild || echo "Keccak bindings compilation fail. Pure JS implementation will be used."


> keccak@1.4.0 rebuild C:\Users\dany.vandermeij\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\keccak
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\dany.vandermeij\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\keccak>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\dany.vandermeij\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\dany.vandermeij\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\dany.vandermeij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\dany.vandermeij\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\dany.vandermeij\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\keccak
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! keccak@1.4.0 rebuild: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the keccak@1.4.0 rebuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dany.vandermeij\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-22T09_38_03_836Z-debug.log
"Keccak bindings compilation fail. Pure JS implementation will be used."
+ truffle@5.0.2
added 89 packages from 304 contributors and updated 1 package in 14.582s
```

I tested the truffle commands and they seem to work, but I dont know why I get this error...

(I need some more text here, so here you have a super awesome Hacker Ipsum: Haxx0r ipsum it's a feature client python else packet sniffer epoch socket. Dennis Ritchie stack race condition pwned warez James T. Kirk suitably small values. Gc continue sql packet alloc leapfrog less gcc shell bytes protected.)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 5):

Use `npm install -g truffle --unsafe-perm` to install truffle this is probably happening due to a syntax issue of keccak which shouldn't affect functionality.

UPDATE (Windows)

```
npm install --global windows-build-tools
```

Comment: Was able to replicate the issue and fix it using this, I'll recheck, can you try this with sudo and check.

Comment: Im using windows, but I try it using cmd in administrator mode

Comment: Ok sorry for that, you need the updated code line as well. But it should work with a updated version of windows 10 just checked